# Treatment of $\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, integration, complex-analysis

Throughout integration theory, one encounters $\infty$. If one makes some special treatment as $[0,\infty)$, then much of the elegance of theorems on 
$[0,\infty]$ would be lost whenever $\infty$ occurs.

What are the possible treatments for $[0,\infty)$ in literature ?

Another way is to define arithmetic in $[0,\infty]$ such that the sum of product with $\infty$ satisfies commutative, associative, and distributive laws hold in $[0,\infty]$ without any restriction. However, cancellation laws for the sum and product does not hold on $\infty$.

Is there any way to remedy the cancelation laws for $\infty$ ?

Comment: The extended real numbers $[0, \infty]$ have poor algebraic properties, but they have some nice topological and analytic properties. This is difficult to remedy. Indeed, most grade schoolers understand how weird infinity is (is $\infty +1$ bigger than $\infty$?).

Comment: "much of the elegance of theorems on $[0,\infty]$ would be lost": please explain. Can you give an example ?

Comment: $\infty+1$ and $\infty$, and $\infty+2$

Comment: Such as Lebesgue's  Monotone Convergence Theorem

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sphere

there are number systems that accept infinity but don't work very well unless analytic

Comment: @Tom The usual cancellation laws are logically inconsistent with the extension of addition to $[0\infty]$. The only way to "remedy" that is to not insist on those laws. You'd have to weaken them, or drop one of the other assumptions previously made. Something has to give.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: As a simple example, in the extended real numbers, the least upper bound property has the simpler form "every subset has a least upper bound".

Comment: @Hurkyl: I was expecting Tom's opinion.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: I already replied earlier. monotone convergence theorem and the dominated convergence theorem which expects functions to take infinite values.

Comment: @tom: yep, you mentioned "Lebesgue's Monotone Convergence Theorem". Can you elaborate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing to *remedy*; there's nothing *wrong* with them! The cancellation laws of the extended real numbers — in particular that you can't cancel $\pm\infty$ — are already exactly what you want them to be for the typical applications of the number system.

There are other number systems available for serving other purposes. One number system that has cancelable infinite numbers and is useful for doing real analysis is the *hyperreal numbers* (although they are only useful if you use the methods of *nonstandard analysis*).

The positive infinite numbers can serve as *approximations* to $+\infty$ (they are all still strictly less than $+\infty$), but they still satisfy all of the laws of arithmetic. In fact, they satisfy all of the laws of analysis too (when interpreted *internally*)!